# MDX ParallelPeriod CurrentMember

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx

I want to select `[paid amt]` of "2006 Quarter 1" and the `ParallelPeriod` which is "2005 Quarter 1". My query is below:

```
WITH

MEMBER [Measures].[ParallelPeriod Qtr] AS 
PARALLELPERIOD( [Svc Date].[Svc Date].[Svc Qtr], 4, [Svc Date].[Svc Date].CURRENTMEMBER )

SELECT  
NON EMPTY 
{ [Measures].[Pd Amt], [Measures].[ParallelPeriod Qtr] } 
ON COLUMNS, 
NON EMPTY 
{
[Svc Date].[Svc Date].[Svc Qtr].&[20061]
} 
ON ROWS 

FROM [health costings model]
```

But the `[Measures].[ParallelPeriod Qtr]` doesn't return the value.

Does anyone know what is wrong with my MDX query? Or is there any other way to generate Period over Period Variance. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to use your Year level and find the euivalent quarter of the previous year?

Does the following return anything?

```
SELECT  
  NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Pd Amt], [Measures].[ParallelPeriod Qtr] } ON COLUMNS, 
  NON EMPTY 
    PARALLELPERIOD( 
       [Svc Date].[Svc Date].[Svc Year]
     , 1
     , [Svc Date].[Svc Date].[Svc Qtr].&[20061] 
    )
  ON ROWS 
FROM [health costings model];
```

In terms of what you were originally doing you may as well not bother with the function `PARALLELPERIOD` as you could just try using `.LAG(4)`. So it probably gets simplified to:

```
SELECT  
  NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Pd Amt], [Measures].[ParallelPeriod Qtr] } ON COLUMNS, 
  NON EMPTY 
     [Svc Date].[Svc Date].[Svc Qtr].&[20061].LAG(4)
  ON ROWS 
FROM [health costings model];
```

If you'd like to continus with a `WITH` clause then we could use the above in a tuple:

```
WITH 
MEMBER [Measures].[ParallelPeriod Qtr] AS 
   (
     [Svc Date].[Svc Date].CURRENTMEMBER.LAG(4)
    ,[Measures].[Pd Amt]
   )
SELECT  
  NON EMPTY 
       { [Measures].[Pd Amt]
       , [Measures].[ParallelPeriod Qtr] } ON 0, 
  NON EMPTY 
    [Svc Date].[Svc Date].[Svc Qtr].&[20061] 
    ON 1
FROM [health costings model];
```